# nginx - Security headers within location block?

Tags: nginx, https, http-headers

I have been testing the security headers (https://securityheaders.com) of my nginx setup and wanted to check peoples opinion with nginx suffix location blocks.

Currently, I get 'A+' for **http(s)://my.site** however, 'B' when testing a suffix location ie https://my.site/location1

The warnings are for missing:-

- Content-Security-Policy
- Referrer-Policy
- Feature-Policy

My server block which receives 'A+' consists of:-

```
    add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'no-referrer';
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; preload" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header Feature-Policy "geolocation none;midi none;notifications none;push none;sync-xhr none;microphone none;camera none;magnetometer none;gyroscope none;;speaker self;vibrate none;fullscreen self;payment none;";
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors my.site;";
```

an example location block that receives 'B' consists of:-

```
location /location1 {
    proxy_pass              http://192.168.1.1;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_buffering         off;
    auth_basic              "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file    /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    error_log               /var/log/nginx/blah.error.log;
```

I have played around with adding the CSP within the location block, however if ths is the way - I must be getting the syntax wrong.

Are the security headers intended to cascade into location blocks? Or is the result of the scan expected? Or am I just noobing...

Cheers, Jonny

Comment: Is that the entire location block?

Comment: Hi womble, yes it is. Just left out the final }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The headers that are reported as being missing are lacking an `always` directive.  I'm guessing that whatever is being tested against isn't returning one of the response codes that `add_header` wants in order to return the other headers.

Comment: This was it mate, legend. I added `always;` to each of those complaining headers. Thanks again, Jonny